# HTACCESS redirecting a URL with no extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

This seems like it should be a relatively easy thing to do but I can't figure it out.  I'm trying to use the htaccess file to redirect:
http://www.example.com/page (or http://example.com/page) 
to 
http://www.example.com/page.htm

This is a very specific case, I don't need any wildcards or any redirects for /anything to /anything.htm - only specifically "/page" to "/page.htm"

I did some searching and found the reverse (from /page.htm to /page) and other cases with wildcards, but couldn't find one very specific redirect like this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm having trouble because it appears another rule in the htaccess file is interfering:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|css|js|images|img|handouts|amp_sections|amp_sections\/handouts)($|/)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|js|png|bmp|ico|css|shtml|dat|xml|csv|txt|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !301
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !401
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !403
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /base.php?page=$1 [P,QSA]
```

So when I put in redirect rules for page to page.htm, typing in example.com/page brings me to http://www.example.com/page.htm?page=page which is obviously not the expected behavior. I somehow need to get the "new" rule to take precedence over this other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/?$ http://example.com/page.htm [L,R=302,NC]
```

Basically this rule is taking the directory `/page` and if it is called, it will change it to `/page.htm`.

Make sure you clear your cache before changing this.

I've set `R` to 302 for testing purposes as this makes it a temporary redirect. If this works for you then change it to `301` to make it a permanent redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just updated my original post with some more info. I believe what you posted would work if not for the "interfering" rule that was already in the htaccess file.

Comment: Per starkeen's suggesion of putting this above the existing rule, this is working perfectly now.  I actually did try putting it first but didn't clear my cache after trying it with the new rule at the end of the file.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad it is working :) Thanks @starkeen for your input and help also.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  **RedirectMatch**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/?$ http://www.example.com/page.html
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this redirect.

Comment: That redirect actually works but the URL visible in the browser is: https://www.example.com/page.htm?page=page  Again, this is caused by the other rule already in the htaccess file (that must remain)

Comment: @JohnO you cant avoid this. Actually, Runtime behaviour of RewriteRule and RedirectMatch is diffrent. RewriteRule runs first on apache. Try thickguru's RewriteRule based solution and put the rules at top.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I made another comment in the post above.